# 404 Not Found when access html under subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I can not access pages under `tw` folder

eg: `about.html`

I will got this error `404 Not Found`

But I can access the `index.html` page

### Nginx conf

```
server{
    server_name great.com;
    root /www/gp;
    expires off;
    try_files $uri/index.html /dev/null =404;

    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /www/gp;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /tw/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /www/gp/tw;
    }

}
```

### Folder structure

```
.
├── index.html
└── tw
    ├── about.html
    ├── brand01.html
    ├── brand.html
    ├── contact.html
    ├── css
    ├── faq01.html
    ├── faq02.html
    ├── images
    ├── js
    └── news.html
```

### Error log in nginx log

```
2014/10/31 12:00:15 [error] 12047#0: *6 open() "/www/gp/tw/tw/images/waves.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 118.163.149.126, server: great-compassion.com, request: "GET /
tw/images/waves.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "www.great-compassion.com", referrer: "http://www.great-compassion.com/tw/css/banner.css"
2014/10/31 12:00:18 [error] 12047#0: *5 open() "/www/gp/tw/tw/brand.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 118.163.149.126, server: great-compassion.com, request: "GET /tw/bra
nd.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.great-compassion.com", referrer: "http://www.great-compassion.com/"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Duplicate root

Just don't redefine `root` in both locations. As you can see in the error log, `/www/gp/tw/tw/brand.html` occurs twice. That is to say, a path in location is inclusive, just like [the documentation states about `root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

```
location /i/ {
  root /data/w3;
}
```

The `/data/w3/i/top.gif` file will be sent in response to the `/i/top.gif` request.